# Controlo ou controle?

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, português-europeu, uso-de-palavras

Qual é a forma correta: controlo ou controle? São ambas válidas?

Pelo Priberam parecem-me as duas válidas:

- [Definição de controle](https://dicionario.priberam.org/controle)
- [Definição de controlo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/controlo)

No entanto, o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/controlo/206) aponta para que "controlo" seja a forma correta

> Controlo, s. m., conforme a feição portuguesa que lhe deu o uso.
> Galicismo - do fr. contrôle - há muito assim dicionarizado, na linha
> do que ensina Rodrigues Lapa na sua "Estilística da Língua Portuguesa"
> (ed. Seara Nova), a propósito dos neologismos. Acontece(u) assim com
> avalancha (e não "avalanche"), avioneta (e não "avionete"), bicicleta
> (e não "biciclete"), bobina (e não "bobine"), cabina (e não "cabine"),
> equipa (e não "equipe"), gabardina (e não "gabardine"), etc. Excepção
> à regra: cassete (e não "casseta").

Comment: São nuances de PT-PT e PT-BR. Acredito que os dois estejam corretos. O mesmo ocorre com Equipe e Equipa, Caminhão e Camião e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

Sem dúvida ambas as grafias são válidas. "Controle" é de uso consagrado pela maior parte da população lusófona, e amplamente dicionarizado também em Portugal.

E aqui vale lembrar que não se pode afirmar que "o Ciberdúvidas aponta" — a afirmação é de um indivíduo, José Mário Costa, não um posicionamento do site (ainda que o José seja cofundador e editor do site).

O Ciberdúvidas publicou dezenas de postagens com a palavra "controle", e a renomada linguista portuguesa Maria Mateus claramente coloca as duas grafias como corretas [num artigo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/acordo/sobre-a-aplicacao-do-acordo-ortografico-da-lingua-portuguesa-de-1990/2779) no próprio site:

> casos de dupla grafia [...] p. ex., equipe/equipa; controle/controlo, louro/loiro, cobarde/covarde.

Não sei porque o José Mário Costa (assim como o [A. Tavares Louro](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/locus-de-controle-externo/24885) e possivelmente outros) se pronunciou de forma tão reacionária, intolerante nessa postagem, mas vale notar que ela é relativamente antiga, de 1997. Desde então ele tem consistentemente defendido a cooperação entre os países na definição da língua. Por exemplo [aqui](https://observalinguaportuguesa.org/fundador-do-ciberduvidas-estranha-iniciativa-unilateral-da-academia-das-ciencias/) e [aqui](https://www.bbc.com/portuguese/lg/noticias/2009/02/090225_portugalacordo_jair):

> “Estranho que a Academia das Ciência de Lisboa (ACL), entidade responsável com a Academia Brasileira de Letras pelo Acordo Ortográfico [de 1990], tenha agora uma iniciativa unilateral sem ter em conta esse contexto histórico”, afirmou hoje José Mário Costa, do Ciberdúvidas, em declarações à agência Lusa.

> Acredito que a Comunidade dos Países de Língua Portuguesa deveria coordenar esse esforço [reforma ortográfica]

Postura essa muito mais sensata. Afinal, como coloca o professor e autor português D´Silvas Filho numa de suas muitas postagens no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-o-vocabulario-ortografico-da-lingua-portuguesa-da-porto-editora/27494):

> entrámos numa fase em que a inovação tem de ser um trabalho de conjunto com todos os países da lusofonia, hoje tão donos da língua como nós. Em especial o Brasil (coma sua enormidade de falantes e o grande empenho que tem com a sua língua, que diz generosamente ser portuguesa) merece-nos sempre que ponderemos bem as suas soluções.

Comment: Curiosamente, o Novo dicionário da língua portuguesa (Lisboa, 1913) não contem nem "controle", nem "controlo". Será tão recente assim sua entrada na língua?

Comment: o uso mais antigo de "controle" datado pelo Houaiss é de 1922. Então, estás provavelmente certo. Aliás, é um galicismo, o que me surpreende, um galicismo tão recente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Sou brasileiro nativo e espero te auxiliar com minha resposta, pelo menos no quesito "PT-BR".

De acordo com as normas brasileiras, ambas as formas estão corretas porém possuem significados diferentes.

**Controlo (pronuncia-se "contrólo"):** vem do verbo "controlar" e significa que o sujeito que está pronunciando a frase tem controle sobre algo.

**Exemplo**: Eu controlo o meu computador.

---

**Controle:** refere-se ao substantivo que dá nome ao objeto que controla (verbo controlar) algo. Porém, também pode ser aplicado na frase para dizer que determinado sujeito, não necessariamente o falante, pode controlar algo.

**Exemplo 1 (substantivo):** "Vou comprar um controle para o meu vídeo game."

**Exemplo 2:** "Eu tenho o controle desta situação."

Comment: Olá seja bem vindo! A pergunta refere a português europeu (vide tag), visto no trecho colocado do Ciberdúvidas. E também é da palavra controlo como substantivo, não verbo. Pode adicionar a parte de Pt-pt para enriquecer sua resposta.

Comment: @sumitani Obrigado pela observação. Sou novo no mundo StackOverflow e realmente não tinha notado as tags. Passarei a prestar mais atenção nisto nas próximas contribuições. Abraço!